# Erro ao realizar insert em uma aplicação Android: "Empty bindArgs"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

## Explicação:

Tenho uma aplicação android que foi feita utilizando o `ADT (Android Developer Tools)` eu utilizo o banco [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) nela e eventualmente realizo algumas operações como `insert` ou `update` e também alguns `select`'s.

## Problema:

Ao realizar um determinado `insert` após executar o `.execSQL()` no banco estou tendo o seguinte erro como exceção:

> Empty bindArgs.

## Código utilizado:

Declaração do banco no `onCreate()`:

```
SQLiteDatabase db_r3Att  = this.openOrCreateDatabase("r3Att.db3", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null );
```

Código de inserção:

```
Cursor c = db_r3Att.rawQuery("select PEDIDO,REGISTRO,TIPOPED,NRNOTA,CLIENTE,NOME,ESPECIE,CONDICAO,OBSV1,OBSV2,TRANSMITIR,DATA,HORA,ENVIAR,SITUACAO,DBREGISTRO,EMPRESA,TROCA,SIMPLES,EBONIFICACAO,PERCDESC,VLRDESC,VLRLIQUIDO from PEDIDO_IMP" , null);
              c.moveToFirst();
              while( !c.isAfterLast() ){
                //incrementa o max
                cPedidoMax++;
                Integer cPedido            = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PEDIDO"));
                Integer cRegistro          = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("REGISTRO"));
                String cTipoPed            = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TIPOPED"));
                String cNrNota             = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NRNOTA"));
                Integer cCliente           = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("CLIENTE"));
                String cNome               = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NOME"));
                String cEspecie            = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ESPECIE"));
                String cCondicao           = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONDICAO"));
                String cObs1               = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OBSV1"));
                String cObs2               = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OBSV2"));
                Integer cTransmitir        = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("TRANSMITIR"));
                String cData               = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DATA"));
                String cHora               = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("HORA"));
                Integer cEnviar            = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ENVIAR"));
                Integer cSituacao          = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SITUACAO"));
                Integer cDBRegistro        = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("DBREGISTRO"));
                Integer cEmpresa           = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("EMPRESA"));
                String cTroca              = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TROCA"));                
                String cSimples            = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SIMPLES"));                  
                String cBonificacao        = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EBONIFICACAO"));                 
                float cPercentualDesconto  = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("PERCDESC"));                  
                float cValorDesconto       = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("VLRDESC"));               
                float cValorLiquido        = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex("VLRLIQUIDO"));
                sb.append("INSERT INTO PEDIDO (PEDIDO,REGISTRO,TIPOPED,NRNOTA,CLIENTE,NOME,ESPECIE,CONDICAO,OBSV1,OBSV2,TRANSMITIR,DATA,HORA,ENVIAR,SITUACAO,DBREGISTRO,EMPRESA,TROCA,SIMPLES,EBONIFICACAO,PERCDESC,VLRDESC,VLRLIQUIDO,ID_PEDIDO_EXT)");
                sb.append(" VALUES ("+cPedidoMax+","+cRegistro+",'"+cTipoPed+"','"+cNrNota+"',"+cCliente+",'"+cNome+"','"+cEspecie+"','"+cCondicao+"','"+cObs1+"','"+cObs2+"',"+cTransmitir+",'"+cData+"','"+cHora+"',"+cEnviar+","+cSituacao+","+cDBRegistro+","+cEmpresa+",'"+cTroca+"','"+cSimples+"','"+cBonificacao+"',"+cPercentualDesconto+","+cValorDesconto+","+cValorLiquido+","+cPedido+");");
                db_r3.execSQL(sb.toString(),null);
                c.moveToNext();
              }
              c.close();
```

## Observação Importante:

1 - Tenho certeza absoluta que o `select` está funcionando e está trazendo os dados e preenchendo as variáveis.

2 - Eu chequei a sintaxe do `insert` e até testei executar manualmente no banco e funcionou.

**Por isso, o erro está em algo que fiz e não na sintaxe, por isso não se preocupem com a string gigante ali no código.**

## Pergunta:

Como resolver este tipo de erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora na sua pergunta você diz que está usando `mysql`, me parece que o acesso é através da classe `SQLiteDatabase`, ou estou enganado? Se for o caso, conforme [a documentação do `execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> Executa uma única instrução SQL que NÃO é um SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

Ou seja, essa função é para coisas como a criação e manutenção de esquema (pelo menos segundo [essa resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027063/520779)). Para executar um `insert`, é necessário usar uma função específica para isso. Provavelmente [a função de mesmo nome](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29):

```
ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
valores.put("PEDIDO", cPedidoMax);
valores.put("REGISTRO", c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("REGISTRO")));
...
db_r3Att.insert("PEDIDO", null, valores);
```

Veja se isso resolve seu problema. Com o bônus de evitar qualquer **injeção de SQL** que porventura possa resultar da query tal como está sendo feita (ou os campos `c.getColumnIndex("TIPOPED")` etc são "sanitizados"?).

**Observação:** como notado, a versão da `execSQL` com 1 argumento somente [suporta `insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29), mas sua documentação ainda recomenda o uso de um método específico quando possível [para as operações básicas `select`, `insert`, `update` e `delete`]. Não compreendo todas as razões por trás de tal recomendação, mas apenas o risco da injeção de SQL mencionado já é um bom indicador...

Comment: Opa, desculpa por não ter especificado que `r3_dbAtt` era do tipo `SQLiteDatabase`! ainda bem que você me lembrou, obrigado, e também gostaria de agradecer pelas informações, porém uma pergunta: porque funcionou com `.execSQL()` se ele não serve para SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE como você disse? agora estou confuso...

Comment: @PauloRoberto Segundo a documentação linkada, a versão com dois argumentos não serve, a com um argumento serve. Mas a função específica ainda é preferível.

Comment: Qual seria a função especifica?

Comment: `insert(String tabela, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues valores)`. Mais detalhes no link, na resposta. O segundo argumento pode ser `null`. Gostaria de dar um exemplo completo, mas no momento não tenho como.

Comment: no caso seria `insert("PEDIDO",null,"(campo,campo2) values (valor,valor2)`?

Comment: Achei [um exemplo online](http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895) e postei como resposta. Mas como falei, infelizmente não tenho como testar isso nesse momento... :(

Comment: Cara que massa! nunca imaginei que dava de fazer isso! ficou muito organizado, muitíssimo obrigado! :)

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, você sabe o melhor meio de quotar os que forem strings? :) ou se ele faz já isso sozinho?

Comment: hehe foi isso que quis dizer com "evitar injeção de SQL"... usando essa função própria, ele automaticamente quota/escapa pra você (pelo menos eu tenho 99% de certeza que faz - não está escrito explicitamente em nenhum lugar, mas por que outra razão uma função dessas existiria?). *Edição:* sim, ele não exatamente "escapa", mas ele usa *prepared statements*, segundo [esse comentário no SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601866/escaping-sqlite-insert-via-contentvalues#comment15357217_11601866). Ou seja, é seguro, não precisa fazer nada de sua parte! :)

Comment: Muito bom! gostei muito deste método, vou alterar todo meu sistema para funcionar desta maneira :) e adorei também o `valores.clear()` hehe

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o erro.

## Explicação:

Seria porque eu estava utilizando a função `.execSQL()` enviando dois parâmetros ao invés de um e estava mandando `null` no segundo assim como eu estava fazendo na `.rawQuery()` porém o segundo parâmetro da `.execSQL()` não pode ser nulo porque é um objeto `bindArgs` e deve ser preenchido caso utilizado.

## Solução:

Seria modificar:

```java
db_r3.execSQL(sb.toString(),null);
```

Por:

```java
db_r3.execSQL(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Também resolve, mas leia minha resposta. Essa versão sem segundo argumento pode ser usada para `insert` sim, mas segundo a documentação é preferível usar uma das funções específicas sempre que possível.